# Octave function variable undefined

Tags: octave, ode

This Octave code says that `'y' is undefined`
However, if I use a short anonymous function, it will be good.
What is the reason?

```
function fun= f(t,y)
    myu=398600.4418E+9;
    J2=1.08262668E-3;
    req=6378137;

    r2=(y(1)**2 + y(2)**2 + y(3)**2);
    r3=r2**(3/2);

    w=1+1.5*J2*(req*req/r2)*(1-5*y(2)*y(2)/r2);
    fun=[y(4),y(5),y(6),-myu*y(1)*w/r3,-myu*y(2)*w/r3,-myu*y(3)*w/r3];    
endfunction   

t0=86400*2.3567000000000000E+04;
tN= 86400*2.3567250000000000E+04;
t = linspace(t0,tN);

y0 = [-9.0656779992979474E+05, -4.8397431127596954E+06, -5.0408120071376814E+06, -7.6805804020022015E+02, 5.4710987127502622E+03, -5.1022193482389539E+03];


x = ode23s (f, t, y0 );
disp(x);
```

Comment: which package are you using? (my octave reports that an `ode23` function is provided by two distinct packages)

Comment: I use this https://octave-online.net/ Can you give me a working one?

Comment: Huh. I did _not_ know about that website. Sweet. The first mistake I see is that in your ode23s function you're supposed to pass a function ___handle___, so `@f` instead of just `f`. However I tried this on octave-online and I'm getting a "dimension mismatch" error ... _that_ I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Also, your t0 and tN are identical ... was that a typo?

Comment: They are not identical)

Comment: oh, hahah, sorry.

Comment: Do you have any results?

Comment: Right, I have downloaded the package on my desktop. In theory your only mistake is that you should call `ode23s (@f, t, y0 )` instead of `ode23s (f, t, y0 )`. However, it appears there is a bug on ode23s. I think line 145 should be `T(:,1) = (feval (FUN, t + .1 * h, x) - feval (FUN, t, x)) / (.1 * h);` instead of `T = (feval (FUN, t + .1 * h, x) - feval (FUN, t, x)) / (.1 * h);`. You could try saving ode23s.m locally and correcting it. Doing that worked for me. Otherwise, you might consider using one of the other ode solvers provided by octave? (i.e. ode45 or lsode)

Comment: Could you please check what result you got for x[0]? In Octave it should be x(end,0)

Comment: The first element of last row

Comment: x[0] and x(end,0) make no sense in octave. The first element of the last row is x(end,1). Also, I only get a vector out (13 elements, the last value is 2036189018.181818 ) ... so maybe the bugfix is wrong and it was supposed to fail then. Sorry ...

Comment: Btw, this is not a function I use, but, are you sure about `t`? From the examples I get the impression you should just be calling it as `ode23s (f, [t0, tN], y0 )`. If I run it like that, I get a vector of length 81 as output; the last value is 2036210400.0

Comment: Anyway, it's not the answer. The last row should be [   1.0920601198177545E+06; -1.9719312043406873E+06; 6.6852892646843726E+06; -4.0833841182019057E+02; -7.2083121930960815E+03; -2.0579927050199744E+03]

Comment: 6 elements: 3 position and 3 velocity

Comment: Using ODE 45 I got good results, but the error increased with time. I thought, probably ode23s would be better

Comment: oh well, best to stick with ode45 then, especially if it doesnt take an unreasonable amount of time to complete. Sorry I couldnt help more.

Comment: ODE45 error grows linearly ) thank you!

Comment: for the record, the ode45 result on my linuxbox from the above code is very different from the one you mentioned. This is what I get: `[8.5545e+04;  -6.5023e+06;   1.0803e+06;  -1.2753e+03;  -1.2102e+03;  -7.5773e+03]`

Comment: Right. The `ode45` that comes with octave by default gives the result I just mentioned. The `ode45` that comes with the `odepkg` gives the result you mentioned earlier. They are totally different results. Maybe a bug report is in order ...

Comment: Did you get with odepkg exactly the result I mentioned? Or with some error?

Comment: not exactly the same but close: with odepkg, the result is `[1.1094e+06,  -1.5982e+06,   6.8219e+06,  -3.7855e+02,  -7.2759e+03,  -1.6483e+03]`, and this seems consistent between my installed octave at home, and the octave-online version. Do the numbers you gave me come from an analytical solution?

Comment: I got similar results in Julia also. Probably, the initial data is not at enough precision